# Delete function doesnt work in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am working in this project which is left by some other person to me.

The database of this project has been moved from one location to another. Moving the database is done by the owner. This caused one function to stop working which is the "delete" function for records.

For my development enviroment I moved the database locally, than it suddenly works. Which make me believe that there is something wrong with sending a delete request to the server.

The code looks like this:

```
    if ($this->RemovedDuty->save($duty['Duty'])) {
        if ($this->Duty->delete($duty_id)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('This duty is removed', 'default', array('class' => 'message success'));
            return true;
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('This duty could not be removed.', 'default', array('class' => 'message error'));
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash('There is something wrong with backing up the data', 'default', array('class' => 'message error'));
        return false;
    }
}
```

How can I go about troubleshooting my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have you  checked, whether your database user has got the privilege to delete records for the new server.

Comment: hmm apparently, that wasn't it :(

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about your models? I see that you're saving in RemovedDuty model and deleting in Duty model. Make sure your models are correct.

Also check if the models are referencing correct tables.

Cheers!

Comment: Well the saving works fine in removed duty, but the code doesnt delete $duty_id. The code than ends up in "this duty could not be removed". Futhermore, this all does works flawlessly in the local envirement